# wmi .net to set serial port?

Tags: .net, wmi, serial-port

I have a usb serial adapter that plug and plays at COM9 or higher on many systems. A third party package I am using in my software can only connect up to COM8. Is there some way to set a COM9 down to a lower port using WMI or something? I know I can do this in the port settings dialog in device manager, but it's easier for my end users if I can do this silently in software for them.

Answer (score 1):

This might help, not sure if that is a good solution for you

http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

i think you can get the source code so you can see how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/toggleNetworkConn.aspx?display=Print) to turn network adapters on and off.  I'm not 100% positive since I haven't done it, but you may be able to use the same methodology to programatically navigate the Control Panel and do the "port dialog" stuff for them.